# Oracle EBS R12- Query to release hold

Tags: oracle11g

Query to release a particular hold from a sales order from back end.
because we have 500 orders which has that hold,
Kindly help;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to familiarize yourself with the EBS API calls and the ability to search for them.  I googled 'salesorder on hold ebs api' and the first result is a fully working example of how to programmatically release hold using the OE_HOLDS_PUB.Release_Holds.  You can also look at OE_HOLDS_PUB package in ETRM.